# Pandas: For each item in a column, count the number of different items in another given column

Tags: python, pandas

In a given Pandas Dataframe, I need to count the number of unique items in column y, for each item in column x . I came up with counting methods in dicts, but they don't seem to work properly. Example of what I am trying to manage:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[a, 2], [a, 1], [c, 4], [a, 1], [c, 4]]), columns=list('AB'))
```

Which creates the following Dataframe:

```
   A  B
0  a  2
1  a  1
2  c  4
3  a  1
4  c  4
```

Now the output I desire should be:

```
a:2
c:1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `groupby` with [`SeriesGroupBy.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nunique.html) and last [`to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_dict.html):

```
print (df.groupby('A').B.nunique())
A
a    2
c    1
Name: B, dtype: int64

print (df.groupby('A').B.nunique().to_dict())
{'a': 2, 'c': 1}
```

Comment: @piRSquared - Yes, it is nice too. Btw, how are you? Busy?

Comment: I think pandas is more and more favorite and many new answeres coming, what is super ;)

Comment: I think that's great!  I hope that what we do helps foster more people getting excited about it.  You've answered more pandas questions than anyone else.  Only you and EdChum have answered more than me.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.2/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) to find unique values.  Then use [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html)

```
df.drop_duplicates().A.value_counts()

a    2
c    1
Name: A, dtype: int64
```